# Multiple parameters within response.meta.get()

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

Is there any solid refernce as to how multiple parameters can fit within `response.meta.get("something","someotherthing")`in scrapy? If it is posible then how `someotherthing` relates to `something`?

I searched a lot but could not find anywhere the exact answer I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.meta` in scrapy it's just a normal python `dict`, and as a python dict it has the method `get` which is None safe - when the second parameter is a default value that take place in case the first parameter is not in the dict.

for example:
while `response.meta['unknown_key']` will raise KeyError exception,
`response.meta.get('unknown_key')` will return None, and 
`response.meta.get('unknown_key', 'abc')` will return `abc`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ami Hollander for the clarity. You made my day.